# tomcatRun with com.bmuschko.tomcat-base in gradle shows 404 or empty page

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle

I'm using gradle and com.bmuschko.tomcat 2.0 plugin in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 to tun my web application in local tomcat 6 container. If i run "tomatRunWar" everything works fine and in browser i can see my working web application. But if i try "tomcatRun" there is a 404 error that says, that the path "/" can not be found.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.0"
  }
}

plugins {
  id "com.bmuschko.tomcat" version "2.0"
}

apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat-base'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = ''
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir '/src/main/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir '/src/main/java'
            include '**/*.xml'
        }
    }
}

war {
    archiveName = 'Frontend.war'
    exclude('**/*.java,**/*.form')
}


[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar]*.contextPath = '/frontend'
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar]*.reloadable = true
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar]*.configFile = file('src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml')
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar]*.httpPort = 8080
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar, tomcatStop]*.stopPort = 8081
[tomcatRun, tomcatStop]*.stopKey = 'stopKey'

task run << {
    //println "Stopping tomcat container"
    //tomcatStop.execute()

    println "Start tomcat container"

    //tomcatRunWar.execute()
    tomcatRun.execute()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5',
                    'javax.servlet:jsp-api:2.0'

    def tomcatVersion = '6.0.35'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat:catalina:${tomcatVersion}",
           "org.apache.tomcat:coyote:${tomcatVersion}",
           "org.apache.tomcat:jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
}
```

What's wrong in my build.gradle? What is the difference between the startup from "tomcatRunWar" and "tomcatRun"?
The startup log from "tomcatRun" shows this ("tomcatRunWar" don't show the error message):

```
The Server is running at http://localhost:8080/frontend
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/testuser/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.1-bin/2pk0g2l49n2sbne636fhtlet6a/gradle-2.1/lib/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/testuser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.2/7539c264413b9b1ff9841cd00058c974b7cd1ec9/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Here is my context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/frontend"/>
```

Comment: Try to run the task with `-i` or `-d`. Does the log show anything relevant?

Comment: General comments: You might want to look into the conventions that the plugins provide for you. They have default values which you are setting nevertheless. Also never call a task's `execute()` method directly. Does `context.xml` define a custom context path? If yes, it will probably take presedence over the `contextPath` variable.

Comment: Changed my question and added context.xml... the path is exact the same. If i call tomcatRunWar.execute() it works like a charm. But tomcatRun.execute() or as task itself in the context-menu, this is not working

Comment: The log difference between the two tasks, show for "tomcatRun": Webapp source directory = ...; for "tomcarRunWar": Web application WAR = ...